I saw a movie in the 90's about a kid that gets a horrible disease
I saw a movie in the 90's about a kid that gets a horrible sickness (I don't know exactly what illness) at a very fragile age. At that time, not much was known about that sickness he had and her mother and father try their best to find what their little child was suffering from. 
The movie shows almost their entire struggle, how the sickness was getting worse and worse (the kid started moving worse and worse until he couldn't walk anymore) from the age when the kid was very small until he was almost a grown-up. 
I believe by the end of the movie, doctors found a cure for that disease, but it was too late to save the kid, even though the cure would be able to save others after him!

Was the child male or female?  You refer to the child as both "he" and "her".

Could it be Lorenzo's Oil (1992)?

Until about the age of 7, Lorenzo Odone was a normal child. After
  then, strange things began to happen to him: he would have blackouts,
  memory lapses, and other strange mental phemonenons. He is eventually
  diagnosed as suffering from ALD: an extremely rare incurable
  degenerative brain disorder. Frustrated at the failings of doctors and
  medicine in this area, the Odones begin to educate themselves in the
  hope of discovering something which can halt the progress of the
  disease.


yes this was the movie !thank you so much
Yes, the child was a boy !

@VorteXz Glad it was the right one. Don't forget to mark it as accepted so its confirmed for anyone looking in the future.

I honestly don't know how to mark it as accepted

@VorteXz it seems you figured it out :)
